# MySQL Select html files from root folder only

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a content management system whose information is stored in a mysql database. I am trying to select only the html files within the folder "history" and no other folders that exist within that folder.

```
select p.id, m.display_name, m.updated_at, group_concat(meta.value) as value, p.path
from metadata_custom meta
right join page as p on p.id = meta.page_id
inner join metadata m on p.metadata_id = m.id
where p.path like '%/history/%'
```

The current query grabs all the files in that folder, but also grabs folders and their files that exist within that folder as well, and I only want the files of the "history" folder. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this that I've overlooked....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [regex operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to achieve this:

E.g.

```
where path rlike 'history/[^/]+\.html$'
```

This would match paths that have "history/" in them followed by something that doesn't have the path separator, which means it returns only the direct children of history directory, ending with `.html`.